# Adding mean change values as data inputs on Revman for a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis using Cochrane's Revman software. Very briefly, I am interested to find out whether an eHealth intervention was effective in improving health outcomes (e.g., weight in kg). The comparison is between an Intervention group and Control group. The studies I have included in my meta-analysis have different intervention duration (e.g., 3 months, 6 months, 1 year).
As I'm conducting the analysis on Revman, I'm not sure about what mean and SD data I should input so that the forest plots can be produced. I've read that inputing follow-up data might not be very accurate or valid as the studies have very different intervention duration.

As I'm also mainly interested in the change of mean from baseline to follow-up (i.e. mean difference in weight between baseline and follow-up in both intervention and control group), will it be acceptable for me to input the mean change values into Revman? I understand that reporting mean change values would mean that it is harder to input changes in SD (as some studies do not report this value), but it seems that Cochrane has suggested ways in obtaining these SD values (https://handbook-5-1.cochrane.org/chapter_7/7_7_3_3_obtaining_standard_deviations_from_standard_errors.htm).

Please help advise if the reasoning behind my steps in inputing mean change values to Revman seems sound!

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: It sounds as though you need to do a meta-regression with intervention duration as a moderator although your post is not very clear about that. Note that questions about how to use a specific piece of software are usually seen as off-topic here and better asked on the support forum for that software.